# Why icons not continuing vertically?

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried creating icons that is aligned vertically per text

here's what it looks like

[image]

but only up to 4 vertically icons can only shown, why it is not continuing?

is it also possible to automatically add these vertical icons if a new schedule has been created?

here's the class where i input information

```
import 'StudentSchedulePage.dart';

class StudentAttendancePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const StudentAttendancePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xffFFFCF8),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 8, 8, 2),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 40,
                      width: 120,
                      child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            PageRouteBuilder(
                              pageBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                                  Animation<double> animation1,
                                  Animation<double> animation2) {
                                return StudentSchedulePage();
                              },
                              transitionDuration: Duration.zero,
                              reverseTransitionDuration: Duration.zero,
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          'Schedule',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                        ),
                        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                            ),
                            backgroundColor: Color(0xffFFFCF8),
                            foregroundColor: Color(0xff71A260)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 120,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 40,
                      width: 120,
                      child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child:
                            Text('Attendance', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17)),
                        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                            ),
                            backgroundColor: Color(0xff71A260),
                            foregroundColor: Color(0xffFFFCF8)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Divider(
                color: Color(0xff71A260).withOpacity(1),
                thickness: 3,
              ),
              AttendanceBox(
                  FirstIcon: Icons.check_circle,
                  SecondIcon: Icons.add_circle,
                  ThirdIcon: Icons.add_circle,
                  FourthIcon: Icons.add_circle,
                  FifthIcon: Icons.check_circle,
                  SixthIcon: Icons.add_circle,
                  Height: 105,
                  Width: 360,
                  Date: 'MONDAY - February 1',
                  Schedule: '8:00-9:00 am class (Science)\n'
                      '12:00 pm at gym for orientation\n'
                      '3:00 pm dismissal'),
              AttendanceBox(
                  FirstIcon: Icons.cancel,
                  SecondIcon: Icons.mail,
                  ThirdIcon: Icons.add_circle,
                  FourthIcon: Icons.add_circle,
                  Height: 80,
                  Width: 360,
                  Date: 'TUESDAY - February 2',
                  Schedule: '7:00 am class (Math)\n'
                      '8:00 am class (English)'),
              AttendanceBox(
                  FirstIcon: Icons.check_circle,
                  SecondIcon: Icons.add_circle,
                  Height: 60,
                  Width: 360,
                  Date: 'WEDNESDAY - February 3',
                  Schedule: 'No Classes\n'),
              AttendanceBox(
                  FirstIcon: Icons.check_circle,
                  SecondIcon: Icons.add_circle,
                  ThirdIcon: Icons.add_circle,
                  FourthIcon: Icons.add_circle,
                  FifthIcon: Icons.check_circle,
                  SixthIcon: Icons.add_circle,
                  SeventhIcon: Icons.check_circle,
                  EightIcon: Icons.add_circle,
                  Height: 125,
                  Width: 360,
                  Date: 'THURSDAY - February 4',
                  Schedule: '10:00-11:00 am class (Filipino)\n'
                      '11:00-12:00 pm class (MAPEH)\n'
                      '12:00-12:30 pm lunch\n'
                      '12:30-1:30 pm (Literature)'),
              SizedBox(
                height: 160,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18),
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 40,
                    width: 100,
                    child: TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                              return ProfilePage();
                            },
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'Back',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                      ),
                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)),
                        backgroundColor: Color(0xff71A260),
                        foregroundColor: Color(0xffFFFCF8),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here's the class for the design

```
class AttendanceBox extends StatelessWidget {
  final IconData? FirstIcon;
  final IconData? SecondIcon;
  final IconData? ThirdIcon;
  final IconData? FourthIcon;
  final IconData? FifthIcon;
  final IconData? SixthIcon;
  final IconData? SeventhIcon;
  final IconData? EightIcon;

  final double Height;
  final double Width;
  final String Date;
  final String Schedule;
  const AttendanceBox(
      {super.key,
      this.FirstIcon,
      this.SecondIcon,
      this.ThirdIcon,
      this.FourthIcon,
      this.FifthIcon,
      this.SixthIcon,
      this.SeventhIcon,
      this.EightIcon,
      required this.Height,
      required this.Width,
      required this.Date,
      required this.Schedule});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 8, 15, 8),
      child: Container(
        height: Height,
        width: Width,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(0xff71A260), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
        child: ListTile(
          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 15, 5),
          title: Text(
            Date,
            style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 17,
                color: Color(0xffFFFCF8),
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                height: 1.4),
          ),
          subtitle: Text(
            Schedule,
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
                color: Color(0xffFFFCF8).withOpacity(1),
                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                height: 1.4),
          ),
          trailing: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 12, 8, 0),
              child: Wrap(
                direction: Axis.vertical,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 20,
                    child: Wrap(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(
                          FirstIcon,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 10),
                        Icon(SecondIcon),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 2,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 20,
                    child: Wrap(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(ThirdIcon),
                        SizedBox(width: 10),
                        Icon(FourthIcon),
                        SizedBox(height: 2,)
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 2,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 20,
                    child: Wrap(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(FifthIcon),
                        SizedBox(width: 10),
                        Icon(SixthIcon),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 2,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 20,
                    child: Wrap(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(SeventhIcon),
                        SizedBox(width: 10),
                        Icon(EightIcon),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I already tried SingleChildScrollView but it is still not working.

Comment: You may try with row and try not to provide fixed size + check the padding

Comment: It is still not working